# GFCI for outdoor outlet?

Tags: receptacle, outdoor

I’m looking to add an outlet outside. The circuit I’d like to tap into currently has a gfci 2 outlets “up” line from where I’d add on. It’s a small circuit without a lot of real load draws. Can/should I make the outside outlet a GFCI? I thought 2 GFCIs in the same circuit trip each other. It would be the end of the line if that makes a difference.

Comment: Outside GFCIs usually do not last as long as inside ones do.  How the other GFCIs are wired might make a difference if you need one outside(if they protect down stream outlets)

Comment: Read the documentation that comes with a GFCI outlet and search and read other questions on this site to understand the difference between the Load and Line terminals on a GFCI outlet.  Ideally you should have one indoor GFCI outlet controlling regular outlets elsewhere as needed especially an outdoor one.   Bear in mind large motorized outdoor equipment may require the full capacity of the circuit, so think about what the indoor ones are for.

Comment: If you'll tell us what _this_ receptacle is intended for, we can help you assess whether you can add it to the current circuit or if you need a whole new one.

Comment: Would the new outlet be connected to any part of a circuit that's connected to the LOAD terminals on another GFCI outlet?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you terminate the new wire that is added to the existing receptacle j-box. If you land the wires on the "LOAD" terminals of the existing receptacle then the new wires and receptacle will be protected by the existing receptacle. If you pigtail the wires ahead of the existing receptacle (or doubled up on the "LINE" terminals if provisions exist on the old receptacle) then you will need to use a GFCI outside.

Also be aware the new outdoor receptacle will need to be weather rated, and some circuits that have GFCI requirements aren't allowed to extend out of the room served, kitchens, bathrooms, and some laundry room receptacles come to mind.

Comment: Probably goes without saying, but outdoor receptacle needs a weatherproof-in-use cover...

Comment: It’s a circuit of outlets for a finished basement room which is why it has the GFCI. There would be a tv and probably some gaming consoles directly before the new outdoor outlet so I definitely want that protected.

Comment: @Anthony, I think the question is , What will you be using the new outdoor outlet for?

Comment: Nothing significant. Holiday lights, that’s probably about it.